# Replace "Image" tag with "a" tag PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I have some HTML content like this

```html
<p><b style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-variant-numeric: inherit; font-variant-east-asian: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; line-height: inherit; font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica,
 sans-serif; vertical-align: baseline; color: rgb(89, 89, 89);">'60 Degrees South Bar and Grill'</b><span style="color: rgb(89, 89, 89); font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">&nbsp;
is an imaginative and quirky space that allows diners to enjoy the sea breeze and spectacular views of the Indian Ocean from three terraces. The bar and Grill is ideally situated in&nbsp;</span>
<b style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-variant-numeric: inherit; font-variant-east-asian: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; line-height: inherit; font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica,
 sans-serif; vertical-align: baseline; color: rgb(89, 89, 89);">Stone Town</b><span style="color: rgb(89, 89, 89); font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">&nbsp;on
 the Shangani strip, perfect for a 'sundowner' while watching a breathtaking sunset. Choose from a glass of wine from their international selection or a&nbsp;</span>
<p><span style="color: rgb(89, 89, 89); font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
<img alt="" src="https://green.com/files/images/Restaurants/60%20Degrees%20South-2.jpg" style="width: 550px; height: 491px;"></span></p>
<p><span style="color: rgb(89, 89, 89); font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
<img alt="" src="https://green.com/files/images/Restaurants/60%20Degrees%20South-2.jpg" style="width: 550px; height: 491px;"></span>
</p>
```

I want to replace all `img` tag with `a` tag i am using `PHP DOMDocument`.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
    $src = urldecode($img->getAttribute('src'));
    if (!empty($src)) {           
        $link = $dom->createElement('a', "Image");          
        $link->setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        $link->setAttribute('href', $src);
        $img->parentNode->replaceChild($link, $img);
    }
}
$dom->saveHTML();
```

This code will only replace only first `img`. How can i replace all `img` to `a` tag.

this is the output i am getting

```html
<p><b style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-variant-numeric: inherit; font-variant-east-asian: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; line-height: inherit; font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica,
 sans-serif; vertical-align: baseline; color: rgb(89, 89, 89);">'60 Degrees South Bar and Grill'</b><span style="color: rgb(89, 89, 89); font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">&nbsp;
is an imaginative and quirky space that allows diners to enjoy the sea breeze and spectacular views of the Indian Ocean from three terraces. The bar and Grill is ideally situated in&nbsp;</span>
<b style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-variant-numeric: inherit; font-variant-east-asian: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; line-height: inherit; font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica,
 sans-serif; vertical-align: baseline; color: rgb(89, 89, 89);">Stone Town</b><span style="color: rgb(89, 89, 89); font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">&nbsp;on
 the Shangani strip, perfect for a 'sundowner' while watching a breathtaking sunset. Choose from a glass of wine from their international selection or a&nbsp;</span>
<p><span style="color: rgb(89, 89, 89); font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
<a target="_blank" href="https://green.com/files/images/Restaurants/60%20Degrees%20South-1.jpg">Image</a></span></p>
<p><span style="color: rgb(89, 89, 89); font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
<img alt="" src="https://green.com/files/images/Restaurants/60%20Degrees%20South-2.jpg" style="width: 550px; height: 491px;"></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a case of when you alter the content of the document your iterating over a (your list of tags in `$dom->getElementsByTagName('img')`) then it will cause problems.  The way to get round this is to use XPath which creates a new list of nodes (the XPath query `//img` means find any `<img>` tag), then iterate over this...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xp->query("//img") as $img) {
```

Comment: Thanks it is working.
`$content = ob_get_clean();

$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($content);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xp->query("//img") as $img) {
    $src = urldecode($img->getAttribute('src'));
    if (!empty($src)) {
        $link = $dom->createElement('a', "Image");
        $link->setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        error_log($src);
        $link->setAttribute('href', $src);
        $img->parentNode->replaceChild($link, $img);
    }

}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use **preg_replace** function

```
  $pattern = '(<img)';
  $replacement = '<a ';
  $pattern2 = '(src=)';
  $replacement2 = 'href= ';

  $subject = Your text
  $temp = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject, -1 );
  echo preg_replace($pattern2, $replacement2, $temp, -1 );
```

Comment: What happens if they put something in the alt attribute, or remove it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem that PHP's `DOMDocument` class excels at:

=> Try this

```
    <?php
    $content = '<p><b style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-variant-numeric: inherit; font-variant-east-asian: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; line-height: inherit; font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica,
     sans-serif; vertical-align: baseline; color: rgb(89, 89, 89);">"60 Degrees South Bar and Grill"</b><span style="color: rgb(89, 89, 89); font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">&nbsp;
    is an imaginative and quirky space that allows diners to enjoy the sea breeze and spectacular views of the Indian Ocean from three terraces. The bar and Grill is ideally situated in&nbsp;</span>
    <b style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-variant-numeric: inherit; font-variant-east-asian: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; line-height: inherit; font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica,
     sans-serif; vertical-align: baseline; color: rgb(89, 89, 89);">Stone Town</b><span style="color: rgb(89, 89, 89); font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">&nbsp;on
     the Shangani strip, perfect for a "sundowner" while watching a breathtaking sunset. Choose from a glass of wine from their international selection or a&nbsp;</span>
    <p><span style="color: rgb(89, 89, 89); font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <img alt="" src="https://green.com/files/images/Restaurants/60%20Degrees%20South-2.jpg" style="width: 550px; height: 491px;"></span></p>
    <p><span style="color: rgb(89, 89, 89); font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <img alt="" src="https://green.com/files/images/Restaurants/60%20Degrees%20South-2.jpg" style="width: 550px; height: 491px;"></span>
    </p>';

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($content);

    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {

     $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", '<a alt="" src="https://green.com/files/images/Restaurants/60%20Degrees%20South-2.jpg" style="width: 550px; height: 491px;">', $content); 
        echo $content;
    }

     $content = $dom->saveHTML();
?>
```

Demo :- https://paiza.io/projects/f7ege34jGw1LQsgvHZ01UA

OR

=> use this one for dynamic img path..

```
<?php

$content = '<p><b style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-variant-numeric: inherit; font-variant-east-asian: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; line-height: inherit; font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica,
 sans-serif; vertical-align: baseline; color: rgb(89, 89, 89);">"60 Degrees South Bar and Grill"</b><span style="color: rgb(89, 89, 89); font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">&nbsp;
is an imaginative and quirky space that allows diners to enjoy the sea breeze and spectacular views of the Indian Ocean from three terraces. The bar and Grill is ideally situated in&nbsp;</span>
<b style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-variant-numeric: inherit; font-variant-east-asian: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; line-height: inherit; font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica,
 sans-serif; vertical-align: baseline; color: rgb(89, 89, 89);">Stone Town</b><span style="color: rgb(89, 89, 89); font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">&nbsp;on
 the Shangani strip, perfect for a "sundowner" while watching a breathtaking sunset. Choose from a glass of wine from their international selection or a&nbsp;</span>
<p><span style="color: rgb(89, 89, 89); font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
<img alt="" src="https://green.com/files/images/Restaurants/60%20Degrees%20South-2.jpg" style="width: 550px; height: 491px;"></span></p>
<p><span style="color: rgb(89, 89, 89); font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
<img alt="" src="https://green.com/files/images/Restaurants/60%20Degrees%20South-2.jpg" style="width: 550px; height: 491px;"></span>
</p>';

$img = '(<img )';
$replace = '<a ';

echo preg_replace($img, $replace, $content, -1 );

?>
```

Comment: We can't use this, because the content is dynamic. `img` path may change